# If $(X, d)$ is totally bounded, then every separated subset of $X$ is finite.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I have to prove that

> If $(X, d)$ is totally bounded, then every separated subset of $X$ is finite.

I tried to use the following definitions:
(1) totally bounded suggests that for every $\epsilon>0$, X is covered by finite collection of open balls with $r=\epsilon$, such that $X$ \ $\cup_{i=1}^nB(x_i,\epsilon)=\emptyset$

(2) a set $A\subset X$ is separated if for some $\epsilon>0$, $d(x,y)\geq \epsilon$, for all $x,y\in A, x\neq y$.

I attempted prove by contradiction. Suppose that every separated subset is not finite. Pick an arbitrary separated subset A.
Then, for $x_n\in A, n\in\mathbb{N}$, $B(x_1,\epsilon)\cap B(x_2, \epsilon)=\emptyset$, $B(x_3,\epsilon)\cap(B(x_1, \epsilon)\cup B(x_2, \epsilon))=\emptyset$, and $B(x_{n+1},\epsilon)\cap \cup_{i=1}^n B(x_i,\epsilon)= \emptyset$.

This implies that $X$ \ $\cap \cup_{i=1}^n B(x_i,\epsilon)\neq \emptyset$, which is a contradiction to the initial statement that (X, d) is totally bounded.

I am not sure if my approach is correct. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to be a little more careful with your argument. Note that $x_2 \notin B(x_1, \epsilon)$ does **not** imply that $ B(x_1, \epsilon) \cap B(x_2, \epsilon) = \emptyset$.

Comment: There are two more issues. The negation of "every separated subset is finite" is not "every separated subset is not finite". Further, if $A$ is a separated subset, then you can't suppose that the elements of $A$ form a $\epsilon$-net; totally bounded only means that an $\epsilon$-net exists, not that every set of $n$ elements form an $\epsilon$-net. Note that you didn't actually use anything about infinite separated sets.

Comment: This is maybe nitpicky but you should really quantify in (2) that you mean "for ***some*** $\epsilon>0$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic is unfortunately not correct, as has been noted in the comments - total boundedness only shows the existence of some finite family of balls $B(x_i,\epsilon)$ that cover $X$, it does not mean that every finite family of balls covers $X$.

Instead, you can argue directly as follows.  By total boundedness, you can cover with finitely many balls of radius $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$.  Since these sets have diameter at most $\frac{2\epsilon}{3}$, each ball intersects at most $1$ member of $A$, and so the union intersects $A$ finitely many times.  Since the union is all of $X$, $A$ is finite.